# JSLint - problems importing packages

Tags: javascript, rhino, jslint

I am scripting java using rhino. I have few classes written in java that I am importing in javascript.

But, when I am validating javascript against JSLint, it invalidates javascript saying:

***Problem at line 9 character 1: 'importPackage' was used before it was defined.***

Here is the sample from my script:

```
importPackage(Packages.org.raj.test);
var test = "123";
```

I have selected the option: "Assume Rhino" as well but still, it shows up same error.

How should I deal with this problem?

*Note that the ECMA standard doesn't cover communication with Java (or with any external object system for that matter).*

Answer (score 1):

> I have explicitly added following line on top of my script
>
> /*global importPackage: true */
>
> and it works!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the "Assume Rhino" flag (aka `rhino: true` in the options directive) only predefines a few global variables for you, and `importPackage` isn't one of them. You can see the complete list [in the code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js#L588).

Paul's answer is basically the correct workaround – you just manually declare each extra global you use. This code passes JSLint cleanly:

```
/*global importPackage, Packages */
importPackage(Packages.org.raj.test);
var test = "123";
```